# sfml - textures are not rendered

Tags: c++, sfml

I decided to make a multiplayer game in sfml, the map is a text variable

- one step lower,! - block with a collider, # - ground.
  It looks something like this:
  "## !;
  ! # !;
  ###;"
  I have a special class "Qardrat" that represents a block with a texture, that is, an alternative to a sprite.

```cpp
    class Quardrat {
    public:
        void spriteSetPosition(int Vx, int Vy) {
            sprite.setPosition(Vx, Vy);
        }
        void LoadTexture(String textureName) {
            texture.loadFromFile(textureName);
            // RectangleShape tmpSprite(texture);
            sprite.setScale(sizeX, sizeY);
            sprite.setTexture(&texture);
        }
        void ShapeMove(int Vx, int Vy) {
            sprite.move(Vx, Vy);
            //sprite.setPosition(sprite.getPosition().x+Vx, sprite.getPosition().y+Vy);
            std::cout << "Сдвинулся на " << Vx << "По x" << std::endl;
        }
        Quardrat(float x = 0, float y = 0, float sx = 1, float sy = 1, String textureName = "player.png") {
            LoadTexture(textureName);
            sizeX = sx;
            sizeY = sy;
            sprite.setPosition(x, y);
            sprite.setSize(Vector2f(sx, sy));
        }
        sf::RectangleShape GetShape() {
            return sprite;
        }
        void DrawShape() {
            ::window.draw(sprite);
        }
        float GetSizeX() {
            return sizeX;
        }float GetSizeY() {
            return sizeY;
        }
    private:
        Texture texture;
        std::string texutreName = "player.png";
        float sizeX = 10;
        float sizeY = 10;
        //Sprite sprite;
        RectangleShape sprite;
    };
```

It is declared as follows: x position, y position, height, width, texture name.
To draw objects, 3 cities are used, which are placed in the square classes:
sloi0, sloi1, player /
here is the drawing code

```cpp
    void DrawOnDisplay(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Quardrat>>& a) {//РИСОВАНИЕ
        for (Quardrat i : sloi0)
            i.DrawShape();
        //::window.draw(i.GetShape());
        for (Quardrat i : sloi1)
            i.DrawShape();
        // ::window.draw(i.GetShape());
        for (Quardrat i : a) {
            i.DrawShape();
            // ::window.draw(i.GetShape());
        }
    }
```

And I'll leave the card reading code here, just in case:

```cpp
 

    for (char block : map) {
                if (block == '#') {
                    Quardrat bl = Quardrat(BlockPosX * StandartBlockSize, BlockPosY * StandartBlockSize, StandartBlockSize, StandartBlockSize);
                  sloi0.push_back(bl); BlockPosX++;
               // }
                if (block == '!') {
                    Quardrat bl = Quardrat(BlockPosX * StandartBlockSize, BlockPosY * StandartBlockSize, 
                   StandartBlockSize / 10, StandartBlockSize / 10, "block.png");
                    sloi0.push_back(bl); BlockPosX++;
                    collisions.push_back(bl);
                }
                if (block == ';') {
                    BlockPosY++;
                    BlockPosX = 0;
                }
            }
```

And here's the problem - from all the blocks of the map, a texture appears only for one, for all the rest - a white square.

Comment: The forum does not allow me to change the question, so I'll do it here. ; - one step lower

Comment: Yes you can edit your question. Here click this, [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65714709/edit)

Comment: Maybe you come from a Java backgroundo, idk, but you shouldn't do `Object foo = Object(a1, a2)`. Instead, initialize your objects like this: `Object foo(a1, a2)`. I'm not sure if in this case that could solve your problem, but as you don't have a copy constructor, give it a try.